# Windows 7/Bluetooth Headset : Microphone has disappeared

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, bluetooth, microphone

Windows 7/64 using Skype with H800 Logitech Headset. I can still hear through the headset but the microphone does not work and as far as Windows is concerned the H800 no longer has a microphone.

This setup has been working as it should except that from time to time the headset would not be able to connect to the laptop and a reboot would fix that.

Last week to save having to do a reboot I went into the Sound Properties dialog ...

[image]

...and hoping that I could disable and then re-enable the microphone and that this would "make things work". Instead (as can be seen in the screen dump) the reference to the H800 disappeared and I can't work out how to make it come back.

On the playback tab the headset is still visible ...
[image]

... and as I say the audio-out part of the headset still works as you would expect.

I have tried going into "Devices and Printers" and doing "Remove Device" followed by "Add Device" and while this does remove and add the headset the inability for the headset to act as a microphone still continues.

Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer ! Followed instructions here and it fixed it : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows7/open-the-recording-audio-troubleshooter .

Don't know why the only way I could achieve that was via "Troubleshooter" ... perhaps because that was run as Admin and my other efforts were not ? But then when I tried before it wasn't as if there was a greyed out option . Anyway it now works and I leave this here in case it's of some use to others in the future.

Comment: Link no longer works :(